# Is my implementation of Salting and SHA-512 hashing passwords correct/secure?

Tags: java, security, cryptography, salt, sha512

Is my implementation of Salting and SHA-512 hashing passwords correct/secure?

I know that I should iterate the algorithm a couple of times on the salted password. Other than that what more should i implement to make it secure or is this enough?

```
        public static String[] SHA512(String password)
{
    //Generates the salt
    SecureRandom saltRandomizer = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[64]; //The same size as the output of SHA-512 (512 bits = 64 bytes)
    saltRandomizer.nextBytes(salt);
    String encodedSalt = Base64.encodeToString(salt, Base64.DEFAULT);


    //Prepends the salt to the password
    String saltedPassword = encodedSalt + password;

    //Hashed the salted password using SHA-512
    MessageDigest digester;
    byte[] digest = null;
    try {
        digester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
        digester.reset();
        digester.update(saltedPassword.getBytes());
        digest = digester.digest();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("No such algorithm");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] passwordPlusSalt = new String[2];
    passwordPlusSalt[0] = Base64.encodeToString(digest, Base64.DEFAULT);
    passwordPlusSalt[1] = encodedSalt;
    return passwordPlusSalt;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't look too bad - to be honest I would just use [jBCrypt](http://www.mindrot.org/projects/jBCrypt/). It deals with hashing with salt, storing the salt and then verification. Writing all that code yourself is a little like playing with fire.

Comment: The lack of iterations is a big flaw. You should have 10000 or so iterations, not just "a couple". (Unless you're fan of *slight* understatements).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is not secure. Take a look at this line:

```
SecureRandom saltRandomizer = new SecureRandom();
```

I notice you don't specify a PRNG or provider. I'm no expert but I understand the SUN CSP default is to use sun.security.provider.NativePRNG on Solaris and Linux, which simply provides the output of /dev/urandom which may (or may not) be suitable for your needs (it is not, for example, recommended for the generation of cryptographic keys).

It is therefore recommended to always specify a PRNG and provider, as follows:

```
SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
```

Furthermore, it is advisable to:

- Periodically throw away the existing java.security.SecureRandom instance and create a new one. This will generate a new instance with a new seed.
- Periodically add new random material to the PRNG seed by making a call to java.security.SecureRandom.setSeed(java.security.SecureRandom.generateSeed(int)).

The point I'm making is that security is a complex topic that is so easy to get wrong. Don't try and homebrew a solution. Use an existing library. To quote Thomas Pornin's excellent answer:

> **Complexity is bad. Homemade is bad. New is bad.**

Sources:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random
- http://www.cigital.com/justice-league-blog/2009/08/14/proper-use-of-javas-securerandom/

Comment: `/dev/urandom` is generally suitable to generate cryptographic keys. Reseeding isn't that important either, but since the OP generates a new instance for each call, it's certainly reseeded quite often.

Comment: @CodesInChaos - From wikipedia - '/dev/urandom ... it is not recommended for the generation of long-term cryptographic keys.'

Comment: He is using it for a salt - so I don't think that the cryptographic randomness is a necessity there.  Hell, the salt is expected to be leaked when the hashes are.

Comment: Not interested in debating the finer points of SecureRandom. My point is, even the simplest of lines has nuances that you may not be aware of. So stop home-rolling security code and use time-tested, peer reviewed solutions. For example, PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt, etc.

Comment: Why do you think `SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");` is more secure, or even different?

Comment: +1 for the bit at the end.  Security and date/time libraries are two things you should never try to do yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I think that taking action to hash passwords with a salt is a good step for securing your application and accessing higher security levels. However, there are problems with your implementation:

- not using a seed for random bytes generation
- not keeping track of the generated random bytes to use them for password verification
- using string concatenation does not add algorithmic complexity but looks like security by obscurity, which has been proven to be inefficient in security critical environments.

Instead, use a standard [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyed-hash_message_authentication_code) algorithm specifically designed for your need. A list of algorithms supported by java 7 is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Mac). PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 is a good choice.
It can simply be used like this:

```
PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, iterations, bytes * 8);
SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] secretPassword = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
```

A complete working code can be found [here](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#javasourcecode). It should limit the impact of a brute force/dictionnary attack, if your password database falls in wrong hands.

Note that the salt is a critical ring. Depending on your security requirements, you can store it on a separate filesystem, type or load it at server startup. There can even be specialized (and generally expensive) Hardware Security Modules which can keep it in safety.

Comment: It would be great if you could extract the crucial parts from the source you cite, in case the link becomes invalid in the future. If you wish to only share a link, consider to post it as comment instead.

Comment: Could you be more specific on which parts you are referring to? Thanks

Comment: @dst You are right. I edited my answer to add more details and include a code snipplet.

Comment: @Aurum I listed the issues I've identified.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate it. I have learned so much about this topic today.